# Algorithm to fit random polygons in set rectangle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, polygons, bin-packing

I have a set of 20 (example) 2D polygons, ranging from triangles, 4-sided irregular, 5-sided to 6-sided polygons. Some of them almost perfect rectangles, some of them completely irregular shapes. All of them will have from 3 to 6 sides, maximum.

I also have some rectangle, let's say it is a 16 by 9, as that's a typical aspect ratio for screens.

My goal is to find a way to puzzle the polygons inside the rectangle wasting the minimum of space.

I can rotate them, scale them up, or down, move them anywhere within the rectangle. Only rule is to do this while maintaining them visually pleasing (don't wanna scale them too big or too small, don't wanna rotate them more than +- 45 degrees if possible).

As asked, here's an example image:

[image]

On the left we see an acceptable result, and on the right, the input.

I have thought of teaching an AI go do this job, but is there any algorithm that can help with this?
Keep in mind that once I place some polygons to the rectangle, I procedurally will keep adding more to it upon a request.

Comment: Don't teach an AI to do the job, find an algorithm that reads set of 2D ploys and do the job for you. I can help you picking the right one or implementing it but you need to explain me more your problem.

Comment: Oussama, I thought that I had explained, but in any case:

Comment: I have a canvas (SVG based), which acts as the rectangle. In this rectangle I want to fill various triangles, and polygons with up to 6 sides.
I can rotate, scale, and move any of them.
I don't want them to overlap, and I don't want them to leave white space.
If a polygon is on the left, or right corner, I can make it overflow the rectangle (a bit), in order to have everything filled in as much as possible.

Comment: For this kind of question, you should probably add one or more images to explain what the desired output is.

Comment: Thanks for helping out / at least trying. I have added an image describing what is an Acceptable solution to the problem (most probably not the best). On the image you can see some examples of what the program WILL encounter, and if it is able to sort them at least as badly as me on photoshop, I will obey the AI gods forever and ever. 
Notice that polys were rotated(+/-45º), scaled (not too big, not too small) & obviously moved.

Comment: google `bin-packing`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an AI to solve it, you need to establish a utility function to be optimized.

It could be defined in terms of:

- Contiguous used area (e.g: how well pieces fit together)
- Area of pieces inside
- Area of pieces outside